# linux load balance for multi core

Tags: linux, multiprocessing, load-balancing

I want to know the load balancing policy Linux uses to balance load/core in multi core architecture, I did a lot of search on google, stackoverflow but not able to get useful material. I need this information for my project, if possible please try to help me.

Comment: A search for "linux multicore cpu balance algorithm" turns up lots of hits.

Answer (score 2):

This might help. [linux-load-balancing-implementation](http://www.techfuels.com/general-software-terms/11084-linux-load-balancing-implementation.html)